# WebException timeout with HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() in Monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I still working on learning Xamarin.iOs and randomly (sometime on the simulator but more often on the device), I've a timeout exception calling HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() in an async method. However, I create a new HttpWebRequest each time the method is called and I think I properly close and dispose everything. Here's a snippet of the code :

```
private async static Task<T> internalCallService<T>(ILogger logger,string url, string body, string httpVerb, string contentType)
{
    T result = default(T);
    WebRequest wr=null;
    try
    {
        logger.Log("Calling {0} started", url);
        wr = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.ContentType = contentType;
        wr.Method = httpVerb;
        wr.Timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
        byte[] streamContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
        using (Stream dataStream = wr.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(streamContent, 0, streamContent.Length);
            dataStream.Flush();
            dataStream.Close();
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            using (var response = (await wr.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)))
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    sw.Stop();
                    logger.Log("Time to call {0} : {1} ms", url, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                    try
                    {
                        var webResponse = response as HttpWebResponse;
                        if (webResponse != null && webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                            {
                                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                                {
                                    var responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseText);
                                    reader.Close();
                                }
                                responseStream.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (response != null)
                        {
                            response.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.Log(e.GetBaseException().Message);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (wr != null)
        {
            wr.Abort();
            wr = null;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Any idea what's going on ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the URL HTTPS? We had numerous issues with random timeouts while something (either xamarin or iOS) tried to resolve the HTTPS certificate. We encountered this when using web services, so we detect this scenario and fall back to WCF when it happens (since WCF doesn't seem to have the problem).

Comment: No, just a simple http POST to a WebAPI service.

Comment: There are a lot of different exceptions that can be thrown from the .GetResponseStream. What exceptions are you getting?